# create boost - variant type for general c struct

Tags: c++, boost-variant

I am trying to create a boost::variant object which can hold any C struct in addition to other datatypes .
for example -this is what I want to achieve for any struct I define:

```
typdef struct c
{
 int a ;
 double b;
}c;

boost::variant<??>  result;
c elem={1,2.0};
result = elem;
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: does it have to be a `variant` ? sounds more like you want a `boost::any`

Comment: no,I tried with boost::any. But I couldnt retrieve the data that was inserted into the any object

Comment: but `variant` is to have one out of a set of types, if you want any type then it is `any`

Comment: what do you mean with "couldnt retrieve" ? [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ? why dont you show the code that does not work and the error you get?

Comment: basically, if I change the example above so that result will be a boost::any object , and then say I want to print result.a it doesn't recognize result.a .
(How in general to I print out the data within the boost::any object?)

Comment: On some level, you need to have some kind of constraint regarding what `result` could possibly contain. You can't specify "this object could contain anything!" and then be shocked that the program can't assume the object will have a member named `a`. Are there any properties that you know, *for certain*, every object stored in `result` will have in common?

Comment: No.How could I ? result can contain anything from Integer to C struct...

Comment: @mickymouse You would have to read documentation on `boost::any` before using it, of course.

Comment: Maybe you need to spend some time specifying in your original question, in basic high-level terms, what it is your program is trying to do. As-is, it's impossible to suggest a solution, because it's not clear what your "let me store any arbitrary object without specifying what it *could* be" problem is actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could achieve it by using a `boost::any` as one of the types of the `boost::variant`. But that wouldn't make sense. What you really should do for unbounded types is use `boost::any` (or `std::any`) directly. `variant` is for a bounded set of types.